# Change date y-M to Y-m in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I want to make date from `11-Mar` to `2011-03`. But I think php is thinking `11-Mar` is `2012-Mar-11`. How can i do it?

value : 11-Mar

expect : 2011-03

result : 2012-03 [`date(strtotime('11-Mar'))`]

Comment: are all the years are as 11, or you have years like 99, 98 you can split the string in two var such as 11 an mar and to 11 ad 20 to make it 2011 and have a array where key is o3 value mar match it and then add it to you string with 2011 you should get the date like you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `DateTime` class present in php.

```
$str = "11-Mar";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-M', $str);
echo $date->format('Y-m');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Regards,

Comment: Your code is working. tnx. but r u have any object lass function?

Comment: sorry @Asuraya,  i didn't get your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP >= 5.3.0 Then you can use this...

```
$date = date_create_from_format('y-M', '11-Mar');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Its Ok. Your code is not correct. Thanks. I edit it. ('y-m as y-M)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = date ('Y-m',strtotime('2011-Mar'));

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$date= date('Y-m',strtotime('2011 Mar'));
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The above is good, this is more exact for what you need to convert FROM:

```
<?php

$a = "11-Mar";
$date = explode("-", $a);
if ($date[0] <= 99)
    $year = '19'.$date[0];

else
    $year = '20'.$date[0];

$mon = $date[1];

$date= date('Y-m',strtotime("$year $mon"));
echo $date; // echoes 2011-03

?>
```